# Why can't my Github Actions pipeline run gcloud commands properly trough SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, github-actions, gcloud, cicd

I'd like to automate the deployment of Docker containers to a VPS,
using `gcloud auth configure-docker` to set the proper docker credentials on the VPS.
This works fine when I'm

- A: logged in as root in the online console in Webmin
- B: logged in as root trough SSH from a Windows 11 terminal
- C: logged in as (let's say) myuser trough SSH from a Windows 11 terminal

So, for example, I can do from Windows 11:

```
ssh myuser@vpsip
*type in password*
gcloud auth configure-docker
```

The problem is, the same command fails when I try to execute it from a Github Actions pipleine:

```
- name: Deploy Docker image to VPS
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          host: vpsip
          username: myuser
          password: mypassword
          port: myport
          script: | 
            whoami
            ls
            gcloud auth configure-docker
```

This is incredibly weird since the `whoami` command returns myuser, so I'd consider that validated. The `ls` command also runs fine, so the login was successful, but the `gcloud` command fails with the error: **"err: bash: line 2: gcloud: command not found"**

My conclusion is that the pipeline or appleboy's action somehow messes up something, since I definitely can use the gcloud command with user "myuser" trough SSH if I start a session from a normal Windows 11 terminal.

The VPS is running Ubuntu 18.

Thank you!

Comment: did you already see this action? https://github.com/google-github-actions/setup-gcloud

Comment: Did you try to verify the installed `gcloud` command using `find`?

Comment: @Matteo Said action is supposed to setup gcloud on the runner machine that executes the pipeline. My goal is to setup gcloud via SSH on my VPS, which is a completely separate machine.

Comment: @Azeem I have zero linux experience, and could not find anything regarding "how to verify if linux command exists with find". Any additional info on how to do this is appreciated!

Comment: @BenceMányoki: Using direct SSH to that machine, run `which gcloud` and note down the path (as you said it works with direct SSH so it should return a valid path for the `gcloud` command). Then, in your workflow, you can use the same path with the `ls` command i.e. `ls /path/to/glcoud` to verify whether it's there or not.

Comment: @Azeem Ran: `ls /home/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/bin` than 
`gcloud -v`. Results are: `out: gcloud` and `gcloud: command not found`. If I'm not mistaken, this means the executable is there, but the linux terminal just wont find it for some reason.

Comment: @BenceMányoki: Did running `which gcloud` after SSH directly returned `/home/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/bin` path?

Comment: @Azeem Yes, from my windows laptops ssh session `which gcloud` returned `/home/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud`. I haven't tried running `which gcloud` in the pipeline yet.

Comment: @Azeem But I've tried running `bash /home/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth configure-docker`, and it works! Wonderful! Now I can progress with the work I wanted to get done 3 days ago :'D but anyways, it'd still be interesting to know why it doesn't find the executable from one SSH session, and it does from another...

Comment: @BenceMányoki: So, when you SSH via that action, it's not added in the `PATH`. Simple solution: SSH directly to that machine, create a symlink i.e. `sudo ln -s $HOME/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud /usr/bin` and it should work after that.

Comment: @BenceMányoki: Also, check the output of `cat ~/.bashrc | grep google-cloud-sdk` on that machine.